# checking Leopard Installer build on burned dvd

Tags: mac-osx, osx-leopard, installation

is there a way to discover the build of a Leopard installer without actually installing it?

I have 2 burned installers and one has a flaw and of course I forgot to label the builds on either

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If these are standard Apple install DVDs you're talking about, the OS build on the DVD itself should match what it'll install.  Check this by looking in System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist on the DVD.  If it's not a standard install DVD (so you can't count on the builds being the same), use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist from the relevant package -- I think it's generally in System/Installation/Packages/Essentials.pkg, but I don't have a disk to check at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work but you could try greping the contents of the cd for the string BUILD?